Shell script Dynamo JSON formatting issue when dynamically adding jobs and steps
I'm trying to create a shell script that dynamically generates a JSON object to be used with the AWS CLI for DynamoDB. The JSON object should contain multiple jobs, and each job should contain multiple steps. Here's the script:
workflow_name="test"
run_id="4879-new12122"

status_values=("Completed" "Success" "Failed")
time_taken_values=("2m" "5m" "10m")
step_names=("Build" "Test" "Deploy")
jobs=("job1" "job2" "job3")

json_item="{\"workflow_runid\": {\"S\": \"$workflow_name:$run_id\"}, \"Repository\": {\"S\": \"${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}\"}, \"Commit_Message\": {\"S\": \"$commitmessage\"}, \"StartTime\": {\"S\": \"2022-01-01T00:00:00Z\"}, \"jobs\": {\"M\": {"

for j in "${!jobs[@]}"; do
  json_item+="\"${jobs[$j]}\": {\"M\": {\"steps\": {\"M\": {"
  
  for i in "${!status_values[@]}"; do
    json_item+="\"${step_names[$i]}\": {\"M\": {\"status\": {\"S\": \"${status_values[$i]}\"}, \"time_taken\": {\"S\": \"${time_taken_values[$i]}\"}}}"
    if (( i < ${#status_values[@]}-1 )); then
      json_item+=", "
    fi
  done

  json_item+="}}}"
  if (( j < ${#jobs[@]}-1 )); then
    json_item+=", "
  fi
done

json_item+="}}}}"

echo "$json_item" | jq .

aws dynamodb put-item --table-name my_table --item "$json_item" --region my_region

{
    "workflow_runid": {"S": "test"},
    "Repository": {"S": "your-repo-name"},
    "Commit_Message": {"S": "Your commit message"},
    "StartTime": {"S": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"},
    "jobs": {"M": {
        "job1": {"M": {"steps": {"M": {
            "Build": {"M": {
                "status": {"S": "Completed"},
                "time_taken": {"S": "2m"}
            }},
            "Test": {"M": {
                "status": {"S": "Success"},
                "time_taken": {"S": "5m"}
            }},
            "Deploy": {"M": {
                "status": {"S": "Failed"},
                "time_taken": {"S": "10m"}
            }}
        }}}},
        "job2": {"M": {"steps": {"M": {
            "Build": {"M": {
                "status": {"S": "Completed"},
                "time_taken": {"S": "2m"}
            }},
            "Test": {"M": {
                "status": {"S": "Success"},
                "time_taken": {"S": "5m"}
            }},
            "Deploy": {"M": {
                "status": {"S": "Failed"},
                "time_taken": {"S": "10m"}
            }}
        }}}},
        "job3": {"M": {"steps": {"M": {
            "Build": {"M": {
                "status": {"S": "Completed"},
                "time_taken": {"S": "2m"}
            }},
            "Test": {"M": {
                "status": {"S": "Success"},
                "time_taken": {"S": "5m"}
            }},
            "Deploy": {"M": {
                "status": {"S": "Failed"},
                "time_taken": {"S": "10m"}
            }}
        }}}}
    }}
}


while running the above script I'm getting the below error
Error parsing parameter '--item': Invalid JSON: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 963 (char 962)

This is apparently Bash, not sh...? Difference between Bash and sh

I can't repro your precise error message. I simply get parse error: Unfinished JSON term at EOF at line 2, column 0. Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Doing this with Bash/Shell is not appropriate because this scripting language lacks JSON parse and construction capabilities. You already uses jq just to lint the result, jq would be capable of constructing your JSON. But it is not a good choice either due to its query oriented heavy syntax. Anything else like Python or PHP would be better options than bash or jq to build a valid JSON reliably for what you need.

Look at the generated JSON. You are lacking one close bracket for each new item you add.
{"workflow_runid": {"S": "test:4879-new12122"},
 "Repository": {"S": ""},
 "Commit_Message": {"S": ""},
 "StartTime": {"S": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"},
 "jobs":
   {"M":
     {"job1":
       {"M":
         {"steps":
           {"M":
             {"Build":
               {"M":
                 {"status": {"S": "Completed"},
                  "time_taken": {"S": "2m"}
                 }
               },
               "Test":
                 {"M":
                   {"status": {"S": "Success"},
                      "time_taken": {"S": "5m"}
                     }
                 },
                 "Deploy":
                   {"M":
                     {"status": {"S": "Failed"},
                      "time_taken": {"S": "10m"}
                     }
                   }
               }
             }
           },
           "job2": {"M":

(You can inspect it by doing removing | jq . and the final AWS command.)
I don't particularly recommend pasting JSON together from strings, but the minimal fix is to add one more closing brace at the end of the for loop, and remove one from the end.
for j in "${!jobs[@]}"; do
  json_item+="\"${jobs[$j]}\": {\"M\": {\"steps\": {\"M\": {"
  
  for i in "${!status_values[@]}"; do
    json_item+="\"${step_names[$i]}\": {\"M\": {\"status\": {\"S\": \"${status_values[$i]}\"}, \"time_taken\": {\"S\": \"${time_taken_values[$i]}\"}}}"
    if (( i < ${#status_values[@]}-1 )); then
      json_item+=", "
    fi
  done

  json_item+="}}}}"  # one more
  if (( j < ${#jobs[@]}-1 )); then
    json_item+=", "
  fi
done

json_item+="}}}"  # one less

